# Exposing ActiveMQ using Kubernetes service for springbbot and angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubernetes-ingress

I need to expose ActiveMQ Pod deployed for java springboot app pod and also for consumption on web browser of angular application.
Can you suggest me which all ports need to exposed for consumption by  angular(web browser) and springboot application.
For consumtion by angula application , do we need dns record.
We have nginx ingress controller for exposing.
We have built docker image using apache-activemq-5.16.3

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you asking which ports should be exposed or how should be they exposed using ingress? Usually default ports should be used if nothing was changed.

Comment: @moonkotte Using ingress how can this be exposed , as my consumer is angular application (Web browser), thought of having a dns record for that, How can we make this setup

Comment: This should look like [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout). Please edit your questions with exact questions, errors, manifests, what was done. Providing [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is very welcomed so community can answer your question and not guess.